# Automate Open - Save - Close with several files in QuickTime

Tags: video, osx-yosemite, encode, quicktime, automator

I have many video files to convert in QuickTime. The process I use to convert each file is the following:
1- Open the file with QuickTime app (Default app)
2- File-->Save (cmd+S)
3- Accept Save dialog box, preserving the default file name which is the same as original file (intro)
4- Close file (cmd+W)

start again with next file

Is there any way to automate this procedure by using Automator or any Script?
ThankYou

Comment: Which format are the original files?

Comment: MTS and I want to convert them in mov files

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear possible with Automator, but the following AppleScript SHOULD work for you:

```
set mtsFolder to choose folder

tell application "Finder" to set targets to every file in folder mtsFolder whose name extension = "MTS"

repeat with eTarget in targets
    set movName to my JustTheName(eTarget) & "mov"
    tell application "Finder" to set movDestination to (eTarget's container as text) & movName
    tell application "QuickTime Player"
        open eTarget as alias
        delay 2
        export front document in movDestination using settings preset "720p"  -- This can be set to whatever is available in QuickTime
        close front document
    end tell
end repeat


to JustTheName(f)
    tell application "Finder"
        set fName to f's name
        set fExt to f's name extension
    end tell
    return characters 1 thru -((fExt's length) + 1) of fName as text
end JustTheName
```

This is set up to save the .mov file at 720p resolution.  You can choose from any of the options listed in QuickTime's File--> Export that is available for your MTS files.

Good luck,

Comment: ThankU. I'm trying to apply your recommendation, but I don't know how to do it. I've created a new automator doc, and added 'Run AppleScript' in which I have pasted your code. I suppose I must indicate somewhere my mst folder but I'm not sure where. Thank you again

Comment: The simplest solution is to open **Script Editor** and paste the code there, then Run the script.  You can go to Script Editor's Preferences and check the box **Show Script Menu in menu bar** and then you can access the script at any time.